# Flash builder could not find a connected device

Tags: flash, apache-flex, builder, ipod

I have spent ages trying to get my app to debug on my ipod, however even though it is connected and the computer registers it Flash Builder can't seem to find it for debug mode.
After running this command:

"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 (64 Bit)\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.348139\AIRSDK\lib \aot\bin\iOSBin\idb.exe" -devices

It lists my device so I am surprised that flash builder can't see it. I have made sure everything is updated but sadly that didn't fix it.
Any ideas would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with a 64 iTunes installation and it worked only with a 32 bit version - get it from https://support.apple.com/downloads/itunes

Make sure to uninstall ALL Apple Programs (not only iTunes) before installing the new one and delete both Apple folders:

Program Files (x86) / Common Files / Apple

Program Files / Common Files / Apple

And i assume you don't get any hints by running idb.exe ? Usually you get useful info there in case there are any problems